# IF, EXISTS and SELECT in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in mysql

```
 BLUE      | RED         | WOLOLO (UNIXTIMESTAMP)
 2 ---------10-----------1324123...
 3 ---------34-----------13241323...
 8 ---------10-----------NULL
 6 ---------10-----------NULL
```

What I want to do is verify if there is any row where **WOLOLO** is **different from null**
and **RED** is **equal to 10**. If not, it inserts a new row, else it selects
 blue from it. Something like this (not working)

> $query = "IF(EXISTS (SELECT BLUE FROM table WHERE WOLOLO='x' AND
>   RED='10'), SELECT BLUE FROM table WHERE WOLOLO='x' AND RED='10',
>   INSERT INTO table ..."

Comment: Couldn't you do it in two steps?  Select count(*) from table where WOLOLO IS NOT NULL and RED = '10'.  That would return a count.  If count > 0  INSERT INTO TABLE...

Comment: Have you read the documentation about `IF`? Why not?

Comment: You cannot INSERT-OR-SELECT. That's two operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it up into a few steps:

```
    DECLARE var0 INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var0 FROM table 
    WHERE WOLOLO IS NOT NULL and RED = '10'; 


    IF var0>0 THEN
     SELECT BLUE FROM table 
    END IF;

    IF var0=0 THEN
     INSERT INTO table ....
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

[You have to use `IS NOT NULL` rather than any sort of equality when checking for NULL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide an example, I'm not understanding the syntax for the IF with SELECT and COUNT